# Sales in specific hours - long term

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need query which calculate sales ONLY in specific hours in long term, group by day. For now, I am using or and output is fine for me, but I want to have even month, so it's not solution at all. Of course, it's easy to prepare long term "ors" with conactenate in excel, but - if it's possible - I want to have it in one-two conditions, when i only need to manipulate data scope.

```
select format(sale_date_time, 'dd/MM'), sum(sale)
from dbo.Sales
where sale_date_time between '2018-10-29 06:00' and '2018-10-29 10:00' or 
sale_date_time between '2018-10-30 06:00' and '2018-10-30 10:00' 
group by format(sale_date_time, 'dd/MM')
```

Comment: sample data and expected result will be good

Comment: You want results per-day, per-hour (hour between 6am and 10am)?

Comment: I need results per day, but only for specific hours of days - 6 am to 10 am.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I understand the question - You can use separate conditions on the date and time parts of the `sale_date_time` column:

```
select format(sale_date_time, 'dd/MM'), sum(sale)
from dbo.Sales
where sale_date_time >= '2018-10-01 00:00' 
and sale_date_time < '2018-11-01 00:00' -- all of October
and CAST(sale_date_time as time) >= '06:00:00'
and CAST(sale_date_time as time) <= '10:00:00'
group by format(sale_date_time, 'dd/MM')
```

Please note that by casting the `sale_date_time` to `time` you are preventing SQL Server to use any indexes that might be relevant to this column - so a better option might be just to store the date and time of the sale in two different columns - one for `date` and one for `time`.

Comment: Works perfectly, I ca't believe how easy it is.

Comment: [Glad to help :-)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291325/how-to-show-appreciation-to-a-user-on-stackoverflow/291327#291327)